# Organising async await functions in nodejs/js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I often use this pattern in organising my code in js/nodejs

```
(async function(){

    let resultOne = await functionOne();
    let resultTwo = await functionTwo();

    return {
        resultOne: resultOne,
        resultTwo: resultTwo,
    }

}()).then(r=>{
    console.log(r);
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
});
```

But i want to do `functionOne` and `functionTwo` in parallel, not waiting for previos to return promise. Only waiting last one for return.
How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want them to run sequentially, use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
Promise.all([functionOne(), functionTwo()]).then(([resultOne, resultTwo]) => {
    console.log({resultOne, resultTwo});
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

or

```
(async function(){
    const [resultOne, resultTwo] = await Promise.all([functionOne(), functionTwo()]);
    return {resultOne, resultTwo};
}()).then(r => {
    console.log(r);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can await a Promise.all():

```
(async function(){

    const results = await Promise.all([functionOne(), functionTwo()])

    return {
        resultOne: results[0],
        resultTwo: results[1],
    }

}()).then(r=>{
    console.log(r);
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
});
```